# Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-4.0

I have been struggling with this problem for hours now. I have an web app that works with Active Directory Authentication. Only certain people are allowed to upload files to the server. When I test from my localhost everything works fine and I can upload files to the correct path on the server. When I publish my solution to the server and I run it from there, it gives me the error "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password". I have set the permissions on the folder for myself to Full Control and Allow All. The server is running IIS 6. Can some one please advise on what to do. I have tried literally almost everything.

Server is on a different machine.
Local is on my PC.;

```
if (this.flUpload.HasFile)
                        {
                            flUpload.SaveAs(@"SERVERPATH\" + flUpload.FileName);
                        }
```

Comment: The Server Is your local machine or Different server?

Comment: Can you share your file upload code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below.

```
  NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(GlobalVariablesBO.UserID, GlobalVariablesBO.Password, GlobalVariablesBO.Domain);
            WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            webclient.Credentials = myCred;
            string tempFileForStorage = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(dBO.SPFileName));
            sharepointUpload.SaveAs(tempFileForStorage);
            webclient.UploadFile("ServerPath", "PUT", tempFileForStorage);
            webclient.Dispose();
            File.Delete(tempFileForStorage);
```

Comment: Thanks a mil. This really helped me. When I wrote the path for the database it overwrote the actual server path. Fixed Now.

Comment: if you can give us more details about your code, I think it s not linked to the upload with web App but you are using sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

It looks like more of configuration issue . Make sure that Website hosting server IIS User should have read/write permission to the server where you are uploading files .

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and see if the file is geeting sabed in tempFileForStorage location. This path is  C://Temp

```
  if (this.flUpload.HasFile)
                    {
                     string tempFileForStorage = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), flUpload.FileName
                        flUpload.SaveAs(tempFileForStorage);
                    }
```